# How to auto launch android app when you receive notification [FCM]?

Tags: android

I want to launch an app automatically when user receive notification on app there will be no click action on launcher icon.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30090042/681929)

Comment: Not working I checked this

Comment: Dude follow this https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/16205/launch-application-from-notification-android-edk.html

Comment: @nobalG this was for GCM I am asking for FCM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onMessageReceived()` method, you can try adding your `startActivity(intent)` code. That way, when the app receives a FCM message, it launches the app. Like this...

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.  Getting this error

Comment: onMessageReceived doesn't call when app is background so this will anyways not helping me

Answer (score 2):

Method onMessageReceived() works fine when app in background if notification body does not contain "notification" parameter. All data should be paste in "data". Like this:

```
{
    "to":"token",
    "priority":"high",
    "data": {
        "title": "Carmen",
        "text": "Популярные новости за сегодня!",
        etc..
    }
}
```

Then you can parse it in your code and show title and text in notification.

For example:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
        Log.d("FirebaseService", "Receive notification: ${remoteMessage?.data}")
        remoteMessage?.let { showNotification(remoteMessage) }
    }

    private fun showNotification(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val notificationModel: NotificationModel
                = getNotificationModelFromMessageData(remoteMessage.data)

        val intent = Intent(this, SplashActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ARGUMENT, notificationModel)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, NOTIFICATION_RECEIVE_REQUEST_CODE,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        val defaultNotificationSound: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notification: Notification
                = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(notificationModel.title)
                .setContentText(notificationModel.text)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setSound(defaultNotificationSound)
                .build()

        val notificationManager: NotificationManager
                = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
    }

    private fun getNotificationModelFromMessageData(jsonData: MutableMap<String, String>): NotificationModel {
        return NotificationModel(
                jsonData[TITLE_PARAMETER] as String,
                jsonData[TEXT_PARAMETER] as String,
                jsonData[DAYS_PARAMETER] as String,
                jsonData[MESSAGE_ID] as String)
    }
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Finally I solved my problem Thanks It was because I was not using any REST client so format of data was {key = value} which was basically works when app in foreground

Answer (score 0):

the user has to accept the permission of `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`
here is a link to the solution
[SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW - How to get this permission automatically on Android 6.0 and targetSdkVersion 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an)